# New 365 Outlook

Tags: email, download, microsoft-outlook-365

I am using Outlook 365 app, and I was looking for a quick way to download my emails since Archiving is no longer a feasible option. I want to be able to download the email along with attachment and save it on my C drive for example or any share point location.

Comment: set up an imap email client?

Comment: @essjae new outlook 365 app is an email client

Comment: Thanks, looks that is the way forward. I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

The new Outlook 365 app currently does not support import/export from/to PST files.

Microsoft 365 admins can use the backend to create a PST backup there.

For you, the user, either switch back to the old Outlook by turning off the switch in the top right: (my version is dutch)
[image]

or use a different email client that allows you to create backups.